Will End of life apply to a latest released version of Spring Security
We have been using Spring-security open source libraries from MVN repository for our projects. I see from https://spring.io/projects/spring-security#support that 5.7.x is EOL on 2023-05-16 . However version 5.7.12 was released only on March 18 , so would the above mentioned EOL apply to 5.7.12 as well or do we get extended support for the latest?
Please advise us on this

No it is for the 5.7 line, if you want extended support you will need to by commercial support.

Alright, but by https://spring.io/projects/spring-security#support All current versions of Spring security are getting EOL by 2024 .??

Yes, because there will be a 6.3/7.0 somewhere down te line which will then superseed 6.2 in EOL date.
